# Sveltekit goto a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using sveltekit goto function to navigate to a page using on:click on a div.

```
clickHandler: (id: string) => goto(`/app/profile/${id}/settings/general-info`)
```

How can I specify to open page in a new tab just like using CTRL + Click?

Comment: "on:click on a div" is bad. For accessibility, click events should only be attached on interactive elements that are supposed to be clicked, e.g. `button`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: If an element is supposed to be a link, it should use an `a` tag, that way the user simply *can* use Ctrl-Click or the right click menu to open the link elsewhere. If you want the link to open in a new tab by default, just specify `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manage this from a ts/js file and the code is running client side then you can use window.open instead of goto -

```
window.open(`/app/profile/${id}/settings/general-info`, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular `<a>` element to create a link and specify `target="_blank"` to open it in a new tab.

here is an example of the the code.

```html
<a href="https://svelte.dev" target="_blank">Svelte</a>
```

a live web environment showing that how it works.  [stackblitz Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-w3y2ql?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte)